# Architecture of a cloud text editor

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Hi I am working on a cloud based text editor. I.e. user types in code, code gets run on cloud, user gets shown code - think Google Colab. What cloud services exist that allow me to run code without waiting for lengthy deployment times - Google Colab runs code on their cloud in realtime and I want to simluate that feeling.
I mostly use GCP so if there is a way I can use a GCP service to accopmlish this that is preferred, but I am open to using any cloud's service that works.

I do not expect each user's session to be very long so I do not want to rent a server for each user - and host their code there. Preferably, I have a few servers that I can cycle between users in near realtime.

Comment: If you want something like Colab, you could try: [Vertex AI Workbench](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/introduction)

Comment: How about skipping the cloud entirely with something like [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/index.html#using-pyodide)?

Comment: To protect your environment, you have to run the user code in a sandboxed environment, such as gvisor: https://gvisor.dev/ However, context switching from a customer to another one is complex. I strongly recommend to have an instance per user (could be virtual instance, such as a container/a pod run for each user, or an instance of Cloud Run service (concurrency parameter set to 1 + session affinity activited)). It's not so easy to achieve, but not impossible!